# How to centralize same ERC-20 token to one ETH address using SMART CONTRACT/SIGNED OFFLINE TRANSACTION

Tags: ethereumjs

Suppose i have same ERC-20 Tokens in 100 ETH accounts. To sell those i have to send the token one by one to ONE mother ETH address. It takes lot of time. I heard there is a shortcut way to do that.

To maintain the security i always rely on OFFLINE TRANSFER from MEW. Is there any way to do this without compromising security. In case i could take out the Nonce one by one before doing. Please suggest the best way to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically generate all transactions and broadcast them to Ethereum network.

Required skills:

- Entry level Python or JavaScript programming
- Basic knowledge how Ethereum network works

Action points:

- Store the a list of private keys of 100 accounts on your work station
- Scan Ethereum network and create another list of what tokens the accounts hold
- Generate signed transactions for ERC-20 `transfer()` smart contract call for each account for each token to send them to a centralized address
- Broadcast these transactions to Ethereum network, either directly from the work station or store them on a USB stick and go to broadcast from another computer

Comment: Sir , could you give me the RAW code , i understand the Javascript but as a newbie on Blockchain , please suggest me the following.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot give you the RAW code, as this problem is quite specific to yourself